# The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form

Tags: jquery, django, django-rest-framework

I got this error `The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form` when I tried to submit FormData to DRF. Here are my codes :

jquery:

```
upload(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let data = new FormData();
        data.append('name', ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.name).value);
        data.append('album', ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.album).value);
        data.append('playlist', 1);
        data.append('file', ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.file).value);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/music/',
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'JWT ' + sessionStorage.getItem('token')
            },
            contentType: false,
            data: data,
            processData: false
        }).done(function (res) {
            console.log(res.responseText);
        }).fail(function (error) {
            console.error(error.responseText);
        });
```

serializer:

```
class MusicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    file = serializers.FileField()

    class Meta:
        model = Music
        fields = ('id', 'favorite', 'created_at', 'file', 'counter', 'name', 'album', 'playlist')
```

and view:

```
class MusicViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = (CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication, JSONWebTokenAuthentication)
    queryset = Music.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MusicSerializer
    parser_classes = (FormParser, MultiPartParser)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        file_obj = self.request.FILES['file']
        #dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(JSON_DATA['dropbox_access_token'])
        #res = dbx.files_upload(file_obj, '/', autorename=True, mute=True)
        print(file_obj)
        #serializer.save(dropbox_id='x')
```

Comment: Not sure, tho believe it'll be the server responding correctly to a client side issue, with the request not being formed quite as you expect. I'd suggest inspecting the outgoing request in the browser developer tools panel, and see if it matches what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution . I need to use

```
 data.append('file', ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.file).files[0]);
```